# PyTorch is crashing the jupyter notebook, while calculating the loss using nn module?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, pytorch

```
model = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(784, 128),
                  nn.ReLU(),
                  nn.Linear(128, 64),
                  nn.ReLU(),
                  nn.Linear(64, 10))

criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

images, labels = next(iter(trainloader))
images = images.view(images.shape[0], -1) 
logits = model(images)
loss = criterion(logits, labels) 
print(loss)
```

The code is crashing at " **loss = criterion( logits, labels)** " line.
**Dataset** : MNIST handwritten digits.

Answer (score 0):

In my case,
I solved it by degrading and installing the pytorch version to 0.4.0 from v1.0.
**How to install v0.4.0 ?**
Just change the version name from 1.0.0 to 0.4.0

> 1. pip3 install https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torch-1.0.0-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl
> 2. pip3 install torchvision

to

> 1. pip3 install https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torch-0.4.0-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl
> 2. pip3 install torchvision

This is for Ubuntu 18.04 OS, using pip, non-CUDA installation.

Comment: Sounds like a good issue to report at their Github repo - since it works in v0.4, it should definitely not crash your program with v1.0